# VSCode/Snowflake: How to connect to Snowflake DB via Single Sign On

Tags: visual-studio-code, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Requirement**: Connect to Snowflake DB via Single Sign-on in VSCode

Need help on how to get connected to the DB with VSCode

**Entered details as below**

[image]

**Error**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Authenticator value should be "externalbrowser" for browser based SSO.
Are you able to access this SF account from browser through SSO or from snowsql as follows :

```
snowsql -a <account> --authenticator=externalbrowser
```

Most likely it is firewall blocking the access or incorrect details provided.

Comment: I can access from browser through SSO but not from VSCode

Comment: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00007d8gmpSAA/connect-through-visual-studio-code

Comment: did you find a solution for this @Kar?

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide your snowflake account name.

Comment: Yes, I gave the Snowflake Account Name as `"CompanName.eu-west-1"`

Comment: Here's a link to an article that might help       https://medium.com/snowflake/snowflake-vs-code-sql-tools-and-github-7eab915e10cb

Comment: The above link is for direct user name and password not SSO

Comment: @Kar were you able to find solution?

Answer (score -2):

Currently the Snowflake driver for VSCode/SQL-tools doesn't implement the SSO authentication due to NodeJS ODBC limitation. Click [here](https://github.com/mtxr/vscode-sqltools/issues/713#issuecomment-720877106) to see the issue in GitHub, this way you can check for updates or contribute.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/sqltools-snowflake-driver/issues/13) your information is out of date and SSO capability should be enabled for the snowflake driver on the latest version.